# Docs on which Visual Studio version was used to build Python Windows binaries?

Tags: python, windows

This question is related to [how to check which compiler was used to build Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350780/how-to-check-which-compiler-was-used-to-build-python) and [What version of Visual Studio is Python on my computer compiled with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676763/what-version-of-visual-studio-is-python-on-my-computer-compiled-with).

However, I'd like to know if there is some documentation available that tells me which version was used for a Python release, **without installing it**.

I know that `print(sys.version)` works once installed, but that is just after the fact.

Comment: you could download the msi, extract the cab file, and use a hex editor, and check if there is any hints buildt into the file. for .net files its typically readable as xml, at the end of the file, followed by `PADDINGXX`

Comment: Just check readme.txt in the PCbuild directory. Here are links for [2.7](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/PCbuild/readme.txt),[3.4](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/PCbuild/readme.txt), and [3.5](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/PCbuild/readme.txt).